# How can I mount tmpfs to /dev/root?

Tags: filesystems, mount

My server disk on Ubuntu is full, but I see I have a lot of space in tmpfs.
So I want mount tmpfs to `/dev/root`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       189G  175G  5.0G  98% /
devtmpfs        5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.9G  610M  5.3G  11% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.2G     0  1.2G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: First you should know, what [tmpfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) is and the fact, that everything in tmpfs will be lost on reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Your tempfs is in memory, not on disk.

To free up disk space on your root partition, try an application like **baobab** or **filelight**.